# Telegraf not processing mqtt data

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

I have a InfluxDB / Telegraf / Mosquitto environment in which I am publishing MQTT messages. The data generated by MQTT is not written in de InfluxDB database.

Telegraf configuration:

```
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  ## Broker URLs for the MQTT server or cluster.  To connect to multiple
  ## clusters or standalone servers, use a separate plugin instance.
  ##   example: servers = ["tcp://localhost:1883"]
  ##            servers = ["ssl://localhost:1883"]
  ##            servers = ["ws://localhost:1883"]
  servers = ["tcp://192.168.x.x1883"]
  username = "xx"
  password = "xx"


  ## Topics that will be subscribed to.
  topics = [
    "Bosch/#"
  ]
]
```

This seems to work as expected.

Telegraf debug logging:

```
[inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connected [tcp://192.168.x.x:1883]
```

Mosquitto debug logging shows this as well:

```
8110927: Sending PUBLISH to Telegraf-Consumer-M0uQg (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'Bosch/CAM137/onvif-ej/RuleEngine/CountAggregation/Counter/&1/xx', ... (116 bytes))
1688110972: Received PINGREQ from Telegraf-Consumer-M0uQg
1688110972: Sending PINGRESP to Telegraf-Consumer-M0uQg
1688111032: Received PINGREQ from Telegraf-Consumer-M0uQg
1688111032: Sending PINGRESP to Telegraf-Consumer-M0uQg
```

However, I don't see the values being processed by Telegraf:

```
2023-06-30T07:43:02Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:12Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:12Z D! [outputs.file] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:22Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:22Z D! [outputs.file] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:32Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:32Z D! [outputs.file] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:42Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:42Z D! [outputs.file] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:52Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
2023-06-30T07:43:52Z D! [outputs.file] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
```

I've additionally created other Telegraf inputs that are written to database:

```
[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = false
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false
[[inputs.disk]]
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "iso9660", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs"]
[[inputs.mem]]
[[inputs.diskio]]
```

This means the database configuration itself should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem yesterday and had been digging for half a day on how to solve the problem. I wanted to subscribe to a float valued mqtt topic using the following data config - with no luck.

```ini
data_format = "value"
data_type = "float"
```

The actual problem in this case is, that the debug logging in telegraf is not verbose enough in the case of the `mqtt_consumer` input plugin as there are no clues on what could be wrong.

Then I found your [Github issue](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/13530) where you said that changing the `data_format` to `json_v2` had fixed the issue. This led me in the right direction!

Long story short, I had to use the `name_override` property to assign a measurement name in the input plugin. Here is my fully working config for the input plugin:

```ini
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://mosquitto:1883"]

  # This needs to be set to define the measurement name
  name_override = "airquality"

  topics = [
    "nodemcu/MH-Z19_Bedroom_634939/value",
  ]

  topic_tag = ""
  tags = { location = "bedroom", unit = "ppm", sensorid = "MH-Z19_634939" }

  username = "*"
  password = "*"

  data_format = "value"
  data_type = "float"
```